# julia-lang Check element type of arbitrarily nested array

Tags: julia

How could I check the element type of a nested array assumming I don't know the level of nesting?:

```
julia> a = [[[[1]]]]
1-element Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1}:
 Array{Array{Int64,1},1}[Array{Int64,1}[[1]]]

julia> etype(a)
 Int64?
```

Comment: you can use `typeof(a).depth` to get the nesting level.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very useful attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a clever way to do this with one line, but in the meantime, you can use recursive calls to `eltype` to do this inside a `while` loop:

```
function nested_eltype(x::AbstractArray)
    y = eltype(x)
    while y <: AbstractArray
        y = eltype(y)
    end
    return(y)
end
```

Note that this works for nested arrays of any dimension, ie it doesn't just have to be `Vector` like the example in your question...

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I've also found a one-liner using regex :)  ```match(r"[\w\d]+", match(r"{[^{}]+}", string(typeof(a))).match).match |> parse |> eval```

Comment: @Phuoc The regex approach certainly works (as long as the developers don't change the behaviour of `string` for displaying types), but have a look at @tim solution too - it uses the same idea as my solution, but is probably a more "julian" way of expressing the code. Cheers.

Comment: @Phuoc for future reference, `eval(parse())`ing strings doesn't work in recent julia versions, but `eval(Meta.parse())` does

Answer (score 11):

As it is often the case for type computations, a recursive approach works very well:

```julia
nested_eltype(x) = nested_eltype(typeof(x))
nested_eltype{T<:AbstractArray}(::Type{T}) = nested_eltype(eltype(T))
nested_eltype{T}(::Type{T}) = T
```

This has no runtime overhead:

```julia
julia> @code_llvm nested_eltype([[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]])

define %jl_value_t* @julia_nested_eltype_71712(%jl_value_t*) #0 {
top:
  ret %jl_value_t* inttoptr (i64 140658266768816 to %jl_value_t*)
}
```

Comment: how does this change for Julia 1.x?

Comment: @jjjjjj In Julia 1.2 this apparently works for me: nested_eltype(x) = nested_eltype(typeof(x));
nested_eltype(::Type{T}) where T <: AbstractArray = nested_eltype(eltype(T));
nested_eltype(::Type{T}) where T = T

Answer (score 1):

This is a generated version using `.depth` attribute:

```
@generated function etype{T}(x::T)
  ex = :(x)  
  for i = 1:T.depth
    ex = :($ex |> eltype)
  end
  ex
end

julia> a = [[[[1]]]]
1-element Array{Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},1}:
 Array{Array{Int64,1},1}[Array{Int64,1}[[1]]]

julia> etype(a)
Int64
```